# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli' after Mac os update

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip

awscli does not work after Mac os update.

while running a bash script got following error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awscli'
```

Tried:

```
 pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

While installing awscli got following warning and error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oto3 (/Users/myaccount/.pyenv/versions/3.6.9/lib/python3.6/site-packages)

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
boto3 1.10.16 requires botocore<1.14.0,>=1.13.16, but you have botocore 1.24.15 which is incompatible.
boto3 1.10.16 requires s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0, but you have s3transfer 0.5.2 which is incompatible.
aiobotocore 1.3.3 requires botocore<1.20.107,>=1.20.106, but you have botocore 1.24.15 which is incompatible.
```

uninstall  botocore and reinstall it, still get above warning and error.
Take a look of pip3

```
which pip3
/Users/myaccount/.pyenv/shims/pip3
```

What might cause this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd consider using brew to install the awscli, not pip. You (probably) only want one awscli installed, but you potentially have multiple installations of Python, including the stock Mac OS-provided Python.

The awscli now comes with its own binaries so doesn't need an external Python installation anyway.

If you need boto3 or, less frequently, botocore then install those using your pip of choice.

Comment: used brew to install awscli solved the problem. I think it might cause by multiple version of pip, python in my system.

Comment: Obligatory comic: https://xkcd.com/1987/